# Hide products from others in Bugzilla

Tags: web, privacy, bugzilla

I want to hide some products from a group of users. I set up the groups and products in the editproducts.cgi configuration. In the groupcontrols I set the "to hide" products to NA/NA but that have no effect. In the search-dialog (the products-dropdown on query.cgi) there is still a list of **all** products.

How can I hide these products (which the user is not member of) from the user?

**EDIT:** I use Bugzilla 4.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a combination which had this effect:

[image: permission settings]

Answer (score 2):

Set the group Member control,Other control to "Default","Default". Check on "editbugs" too.
Product should map with The group and users can be assigned to specific groups, so that, the group members can only view the bug of the product.

- Team Creation -A new team can be created via 'TEAM' link
- Client Creation  -A new client can be created through “CLIENT”  link . Here we assign a Team to the client.

The products are restricted to the groups and the users assigned to the specific groups.