# How to unhide the products and give read only access to users in Bugzilla 5.0.3

Tags: bugzilla

I unintentionally managed to hide the products by following similar steps in [Hide products from others in Bugzilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338522/hide-products-from-others-in-bugzilla)

However, I'd like to UNHIDE the products and only provide READ ONLY access to few users to selected products in Bugzilla 5.0.3.

Could you please advise me about this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not programming question (as someone has pointed it out earlier), but hoping if someone generous and helpful person can help me out over here. As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338522/hide-products-from-others-in-bugzilla similar query has been answered over here.

Comment: Following allowed me to UNHIDE the products
1) Added myself to new group with MANDATORY / MANDATORY access (that's responsible to hide products)
2) Attempt to delete that group
3) Bugzilla will list the products that gets affected by this change
4) Click individual product name and change MANDATORY / MANDATORY access to N/A / N/A

Answer (score 0):

**To UNHIDE the products**

1) Added myself to new group with MANDATORY / MANDATORY access (that's responsible to hide products)

2) Attempt to delete that group

3) Bugzilla will list the products that gets affected by this change

4) Click individual product name and change MANDATORY / MANDATORY access to N/A / N/A

**To provide read only access to users**

For each product, do all of the following:

1) set CANEDIT for your existing group, and remove MANDATORY / MANDATORY (if set) from it.

2) Add a new group. Make it inherit the original group's members by setting
MANDATORY / MANDATORY for it.

Now we have two groups; the original for editing, and a new one for
viewing. Because of the membership inheritance between the groups, all
editors are automatically viewers, too.